# Android Appium Python - element.get_attribute('text') returns no text

Tags: android, python, testing, automation, appium

I try to get the text attribute of an element in hybrid app.

```
def test_example(driver):
   el = driver.find_element_by_id('com.access_company.twine.android.dmc:id/btnVideos')

   print el.get_attribute("text")
```

so there is a button with video icon and a text "Videos". Unfortunately the above code doesnt print anything.
So i tried this:

```
 print el.get_attribute("resourceId")
```

Surprisingly that works. So what am I missing or doing wrong here? Hope someone can help.

[UIAutomator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzo1t.png)

Regards

Comment: are you sure there is actually text in this button when you query it? is the text set somewhere else in the code (not in the XML layout)?

Comment: yes ive just attached a screenshot of uiautomator . there you can see the text exists. I have no access to source code but can ask the developers if text is set with different methods. But i think thats not important when uiautomator shows text in text field?

Comment: It could be a matter of timing, may be appium is grabbing the text before it is set. (just speculating, here, I am unsure how appium grabs the text and when your test code is executed)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I put a sleep time of 30 seconds before i search for the element and after ive found it. Still didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After investigating more time I found the solution and i feel so dumb now. There was a button, but this is not clickable so the id i was taking was not actually the button with the text, but the parent which is a relative layout without text. duh.. By the way resourceId doesn't return only "btnVideos" but the full id instead. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For the text of the stated element try the following code :

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('com.access_company.twine.android.dmc:id/btnVideos')
print el.text
```

Also `el.get_attribute("resourceId")` shall ideally return *"btnVideos"*